# Can I upgrade my child's account to an adult account?

Tags: ps4, red-dead-redemption-2

My child wants to buy gold on Red Dead Redemption 2 but they can't because it is a child account. Is there any way I can buy it with my account then transfer it to theirs or at least temporarily upgrade their account to an adult account?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able upgrade the child's account to an Adult one until they're 18.

You can purchase the game on your account or buy the physical version and allow the child to play (by [removing parental control restrictions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsDU1CzsMhc)), but the child will only be able to play offline on their own account - the [child account will be restricted from playing the game online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3AZi666LVs).